# Issue to send nmea command over serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port, gps, nmea

I am using the serialport control in .net to send parm command over serial communication in the goal to get extra status from my gps device.

From the description I found on internet, it is possible to activate the fom, gsv, ... via the
following command:

$PARM,NMEA,7023
The reply from my request needs to be:
$PARM,NMEA,7023*[check sum value] to acknowledge the command transfered.  In my

In my case the return status is always:
$GPTXT,01,01,01,PARM inv format*32 and I have no clue what I am doing wrong.
at the end of the message, I always transfer the  characters.

Do you know what I am doing wrong or if this is possible to send such request ?
Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards,
MiQi

Comment: You need to add the Checksum to end of message.  I think the crc should be 1B6F hex.  Not sure without reading manual if it want character or bytes.  If character it would be 31423646

Comment: Hello Sir, thank you for your reply but the document for example from https://gps-telematics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/AT100_nmeaguide.pdf (page: 27/43) does not talk about the cr/lf but this is something I already transfer and normally not taken into account for the checksum.  I am sure about it because the oncoming static messages are validated without the cr/lf.

Comment: Normally the command I need to send is: $PARM,NMEA,7023<CR><LF> but this is returned as invalid command. Your help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

See below You have the return and line feed wrong

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string NMEA = "$PARM,NMEA,7023\r\n";
            //commands do not have checksum
        }
        static byte Calc_checksum(byte[] sz, int nCount)
        {
            byte cs = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < nCount; i++)
            {
                cs ^= sz[i];
            }
            return cs;
        }
```

Comment: Hello Sir, thank you for your reply, this is exactly what I am doing by adding \r\n at the end of the command string but I thought it will not be accepted by the stackoverflow editor.  I retried today and I am still getting: $GPTXT,01,01,01,PARM inv format*32

Comment: I think the baud rate is wrong.  Make sure you set the serial port to no handshaking (neither hardware or software), 8 bit, no parity, 1 stop.  Then send Baud rate before the NMEA message.  See if the Baud Rate give same error message.  I think the BAUD is correct since the response is readable.  But you never know.  Also try one the the settings in the PDF file like 7003 just to make sure your settings a valid.  If 7003 works then your combination of parameters is not valid.